# Mouse pointer gets larger in Firefox

Tags: mouse, pointers

I'm having serious problems with ubuntu 11.10 i actually reinstalled it for 3 times because it keeps bugging at the start screen
However now it is working i'm encountering a problem with the mouse pointer size wich gets bigger a lot in firefox like in this screen :

[image]

And when i'm on the desktop it gets this size :

[image]

Thanks a lot i really don't know what i should do :)

Comment: What are your computer specs? And I'm assuming everything is set to default and this is a fresh install.

Comment: i see the same cursor with the same size in both images.

Comment: do you have any firefox add ons / extensions installed?

Comment: @Micro — I thought as much too, so I checked with GIMP and yep, same size!

Answer (score 2):

Those mouse pointers are exactly the same size. Measuring both cursor dimensions in [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) shows that they are both 25px wide and 39px high (depending on where you take the threshold of the border blur, of course, but it's still consistent). It only looks smaller on the desktop because the black border of the pointer is not visually distinct against the dark desktop background.

Answer (score 0):

I got a huge cursor in ubuntu 16.04 after a reboot

i fixed it by editing ~/.Xresources or ~/.Xdefaults and adding this line : `Xcursor.size: 12` and then execute `xrdb ~/.Xresources` (or ~/.Xdefaults).

New application should be fixed, to apply to all application you should restart X11

I also tried to start `dconf-editor` and going to `org->desktop->gnome->interface` and change the `cursor-size` from 24 to 12. As i didn't restart, this didn't fixed anything, but in theory should work. So maybe this should work if you restart X11 after.

Try this one first and restart and if it fails, try the above one and comment below which one worked for you.